# Use of masks in SRM 655 Div 2 Hard on Topcoder

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, bitmask

The question goes as follows...
Bob's little sister Alice is nine years old. Bob is testing her mathematical prowess by asking her to compute the remainder a number gives when divided by 9.

Today, Bob gave Alice exactly N such questions. We will number the questions 0 through N-1. In each question, Bob gave Alice the same M-digit number. (Note that Bob's number is allowed to have some leading zeros.)

In some of those cases Alice may have skipped some of the digits when reading the number. However, she never made any other mistakes in her calculations For example, if Bob gave Alice the number 012345 three times, she may have read it as 0145 the first time, 012345 the second time, and 135 the third time. Then, her answers would be 145 modulo 9 = 1, 12345 modulo 9 = 6, and 135 modulo 9 = 0.

You are given the int N and a int[] d with M elements. For each i, the number d[i] corresponds to the digit of the order 10^i in Bob's number. For each i and j, Alice read digit i when answering question j if and only if bit number j of the number d[i] is 1.

For example, suppose that d[3] = 6. In binary, 6 is 110. In other words, the binary digits number 0, 1, and 2 are 0, 1, and 1. Hence, Alice skipped the corresponding digit in question 0 but she read it in questions 1 and 2.

A surprising thing happened in today's experiment: For each of the N questions, Alice's answer was that the remainder is 0. Bob found that interesting. He now wonders: given N and d, how many different M-digit numbers have this property?

Let X be the answer to Bob's question. Compute and return the value (X modulo 1,000,000,007).

After thinking for the solution for quite a while, and no idea turning up, I referred the editorial given below

**Add, don't multiply**

When problems ask you to do things using modulo 9 specifically (ask the remainder when dividing by 9), it is worth knowing a special property about modulo 9 and digits. 10≡1mod9 , this means that all powers of 10 are also 1 modulo 9. Modular arithmetic will make it so if you take a number, a quick way to get that number modulo 9 is to first add its digits and then take the remainder after dividing by 9. For example: 4671mod9≡(4⋅1000+6⋅100+7⋅10+1)mod9≡4⋅1+6⋅1+7⋅1+1⋅1mod9≡4+6+7+1.

**The N modulos**

Let's think of deciding each digit in order from 0 to M−1. There are N questions and each of them represents the total sum of some of the digits of the number modulo 9. We need the final sum for each of the questions to be 0, but while filling each digit the current sums might vary and be distinct to 0.

Let's think of this as a state problem. We start with an empty M digit number and we wish to fill it. Initially, all the sums of digits for each of the N questions are 0. Imagine we decide that digit with index 0 will be 7. This means that some of the sums s will become (s+7)mod9. We do not need to remember the whole sum s, just the modulo 9 of it. Some other sums will stay at 0. It all depends whether or not 0 is included in the specific question's sum.

This allows us to think of a recurrence like : f(s0,s1,...,sN−1,p). Which will give us the number of ways to fill the digits with indexes greater than or equal to p, such that si is the current sum for each question.

Base case: p=M, this means we have ran out of digits. We no longer need to add any digits and the sums cannot change anymore, all si must be equal to 0.
Else we can try each digit i as the digit that will be used in position p of the number and see how the state changes. The new sums will be s'0,s'1,...s'N−1 and they will add i or not depending if digit #p is included in the respective sum. The number of ways to fill the remaining positions is: f(s'0,s'1,...s'N−1,p+1). We need to add this result for each of the digit we try.
This recurrence solves the problem. It is acyclic and the state size is not very large. Note that each si can be one of 9 numbers (results modulo 9), so there are at most 95 different combinations of si. p is O(M), M≤20. For each state we need to try 9 digits and update 5 sums. If we use memoization or implement the function iteratively, a worst case will look like 95⋅20⋅9⋅5, which is very appropriate for the time limit.

Implementing the memoization might be complicated because of the flexible number of arguments. We can work around this in two ways. One is assuming there are always 5 questions, but 5−M of the questions ignore ALL digits.

> The other is to use base-9 encoding to represent the states.
>
> This is very similar to using bit-masks (base 2 numbers) but with base
>   9.

I understood almost everything including the choice of the dynamic programming state. But what I couldn't understand was the use of masks in the solution. Can someone please explain how it was done i.e. the implementation of the mask.

Here is the code given in the editorial

```
const int MOD = 1000000007;

int pow9[6];

int N;
vector<int> d;

long dp[9*9*9*9*9][21];

long f(int mask, int p)
{
    long & res = dp[mask][p];
    if (res == -1) {
        res = 0;
        if (p == d.size() ) {
            // base case
            if (mask == 0) {
                // good
                res = 1;
            }
        } else {
            // pick a digit for the number
            for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
                // calculate the new mask:
                int mask2 = 0;
                for (int j = N-1; j >= 0; j--) {
                    int o = (mask / pow9[j]) % 9;
                    if ( (d[p] & (1<<j)) != 0 ) {
                        o = (o + i) % 9;
                    }
                    mask2 = mask2 * 9 + o;
                }
                res += f(mask2, p+1);
            }
            res %= MOD;
        }
    }
    return res;
}

int count(int N, vector<int> d)
{
    this->d = d;
    this->N = N;
    memset(dp, -1, sizeof(dp));
    pow9[0] = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
        pow9[i] = 9 * pow9[i-1];
    }
    return (int)f(0,0);
}
```

NOTE: I know about masks a bit and I have used them in the subset sum problem. Though it was quite different from this implementation.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!